# I need to find/replace values in SQL table with secondary condition

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, where-clause

I have a SQL table with these fields:

```
value_id
entity_type_id
attribute_id
value
```

What i need replaced is any values (in the value field) with "CA" replaced with "California"  where the attribute_id is 28

It is important that only rows with attribute_id of 28 get modified.

I can do the simple find/replace, but i am having a hard time giving it this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET `value` = 'California'
WHERE attribute_id = 28 AND `value` = 'CA';
```